# print array element in assembly language

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

I have written following code in nasm assembly for printing array element on scree.In this code there is no compilation error but I am getting garbage value on the screen.

```
section .data
num1: dd 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50,300
total: dd 0
msg :  dd "Value=%d",10,0

    section .text
        extern _printf
        global _main
    _main:
        push ebp
        mov ebp,esp
        mov ebx,num1 ;point bx to first number
        mov ecx,11     ;load count of numbers in ecx
        mov eax,0       
    loop:
        mov eax,[ebx]

        push msg
        call _printf



        add ebx,4
        sub ecx,1
        jnz loop

        mov esp,ebp
        pop ebp

        ret
```

**Solution**

```
section .data
num1: dd 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50,300
total: dd 0
msg :  dd "Value=%d",10,0

    section .text
        extern _printf
        global _main
    _main:
        push ebp
        mov ebp,esp
    mov eax,10
        mov ebx,num1 ;point bx to first number
        mov ecx,0 ;load 0

    loop:

    ;store the value because external function like printf modify the value
    push ebx
    push eax
    push ecx

        push DWORD [ebx]

        push msg
        call _printf
    add esp,8

    ;restore thses values
    pop ecx
    pop eax
    pop ebx
    inc ecx
    add ebx,4
    cmp ecx,eax
    jne loop



        mov esp,ebp
        pop ebp

        ret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out the solution of my problem.So I am posting here for other people

```
section .data
num1: dd 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50,300
total: dd 0
msg :  dd "Value=%d",10,0

    section .text
        extern _printf
        global _main
    _main:
        push ebp
        mov ebp,esp
    mov eax,10
        mov ebx,num1 ;point bx to first number
        mov ecx,0 ;load 0

    loop:

    ;store the value because external function like printf modify the value
    push ebx
    push eax
    push ecx

        push DWORD [ebx]

        push msg
        call _printf
    add esp,8

    ;restore thses values
    pop ecx
    pop eax
    pop ebx
    inc ecx
    add ebx,4
    cmp ecx,eax
    jne loop



        mov esp,ebp
        pop ebp

        ret
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Apparently you want to pass two arguments to printf. Then you have to push them both (you seem to think that one of them is passed in EAX, but that's not true).
2. C function is free to clobber ECX, so you should save and restore it (you aren't using other caller-saved registers now, but it's time to read more on X86 calling conventions).